# Enable regular PC keyboard for direct recording Synth1 VST in REAPER?

Tags: daw, virtual-instrument

I'd like to record Synth1 and play wit it in REaper using my PC typing keyboard. I open Synth1 and the keyboard doesn't work as a playing keyboard.
How can I enable it to do so having Synth1 opened?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you should do:

- **Ensure the track is armed for recording** In most DAWs, a track will not "play" unless armed, this is to help avoid MIDI inputs triggering every track all the time by default
- **Enable the Virtual MIDI keyboard** Per [this post on the forums](https://forums.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=85829), one user posted that this is in the "view" menu of Reaper
- **Set the track to receive it as input** There may be an In/Out section on the track, you will want to make sure the "In" is coming from either "All Ins" or "Virtual MIDI Keyboard" specifically, and the "Out" should be going to a mix bus or your Master track. In either case, make sure the receiving channel is routed correctly and at the correct volume.

From how it sounds, it sounds like the virtual MIDI keyboard will automatically receive input from your computer keyboard. I haven't used Reaper personally, so I apologize if these instructions aren't exact, but the process is pretty similar across most DAWs.